Washing machine drive belt stretch over time?
I'm doing maintenance on 2009 GE Front loader washing machine and ordered replacement drive belt.
The new belt is not OEM, but the printed part number  "7PJE 1303" is same as on the old (different font-style and manufacture though).     Nevertheless,  I'm finding the new belt is slight shorter than old belt, by about 1.5" over ~50" circumference (about 3%).
I'm replacing the belt because it was slipping, but no necessarily because belt was worn.  There is definitely issue with door seal/boot that would easily cause belt to slip.  The belt felt pretty tight and was not easy to remove from the wheel, and no obvious wear or frays.
Setting aside the fact that the belt felt pretty tight, is it normal for drive belt to inelastically stretch over time (15 years)?

3% stretch over 15 years does not seem unusual.

OP answer
Nope!  It would seem that 3% stretching is not a reasonable effect after 15 yrs.
After completing the non-belt-related maintenance, in reassembling the machine, I found the new aftermarket drive belt could not be made to fit on to the machines drive mechanism.  And reassembling included reattaching the drive motor:  no amount adjustment to the motor position would allow me to install the new drive belt.
So, in this case, the mismatch in length between old and new drive belt was NOT the result of inelastic stretching of the old drive belt.  It was simply that the aftermarket belt is a P-o-S.

It is normal for belts to stretch over time. Many machines have motor mounts that are adjustable to allow for belts to be tighten if they start to slip over time due to stretching. The old cars had slotted brackets for the various fans, compressors, power steering so they could be tightened due to stretching. I think the front loaders have a spring tensioner that self adjusts but the belt will still stretch and once the edges get worn smooth, the belt will start to slip.

There is no spring tensioner on this machine.  Its fixed.   I know.  As part of the maintenance, I've already taken the wheel and motor out.
